# Form Permissions not working in Module with Multiple Forms

Tags: forms, module, user-permissions

This works great in a module with a single form, however in a module with multiple forms the form does not show up in the permissions list. Is there something that I need to do differently for modules with multiple forms?  For example, do I need to add security to each form before it will recognize it for any forms in the module?

I add this to hook menu:

```
'access callback' => 'user_access',
'access arguments' => array('Spring Grove Scorecard Access'),
```

Then use this function:

```
function form_scorecard_permission() {
    return array(
       'Spring Grove Scorecard Access' => array(
       'title' => t('Spring Grove Scorecard Access'),
       'description' => t('Allows users to access the Spring Grove Scorecard.'),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault for not completely understanding how the permissions function worked.  I didn't realize only one function is needed to house all form permissions.  The following code works great.  Hopefully it will help others who aren't all that bright like myself:

```
function glatfelter_supplier_action_register_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['sar_performance_form'] = array( 
    'title' => 'SAR Performance',
    'description' => 'SAR Performance Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('sar_performance_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('QCA SAR Performance Form Access'),
  );

    $items['sar_sdr_form'] = array( 
    'title' => 'SAR SDR/NCR',
    'description' => 'SAR SDR Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('sar_sdr_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('QCA SAR SDR Form Access'),
  );

  return $items;
}

//***PEFORMANCE FORM***
function sar_performance_form($form, &$form_state) {

   //Display the overview
   $form['fs_sar_performance_overview'] = array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
     '#title' => t('Overview'),
   );

   $form['fs_sar_performance_overview']['sar_performance_overview'] = array(
     '#markup' => t('Performance form overview goes here'),
   );

   //Display the form
   $form['sar_performance_something'] = array(
     '#markup' => 'Form input can start here',
   );

   return $form;
}

//***SDR FORM***
function sar_sdr_form($form, &$form_state) {

   //Display the overview
   $form['fs_sar_sdr_overview'] = array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
     '#title' => t('Overview'),
   );

   $form['fs_sar_sdr_overview']['sar_sdr_overview'] = array(
     '#markup' => t('SDR form overview goes here'),
   );

   //Display the form
   $form['sar_sdr_something'] = array(
     '#markup' => 'Form input can start here',
   );

   return $form;
}

//This function adds the forms to the permissions menu
function glatfelter_supplier_action_register_permission() {
    return array(
       'QCA SAR Performance Form Access' => array(
       'title' => t('QCA SAR Performance Form Access'),
       'description' => t('Allows users to access the SAR Performance form.'),
       ),

       'QCA SAR SDR Form Access' => array(
       'title' => t('QCA SAR SDR Form Access'),
       'description' => t('Allows users to access the SAR SDR form.'),
       ),

    );
}
```